# Is it valid for Title attribute for <a> tag to hold html tags like <br> for new line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My question here is it really valid for a title attribute to hold html tags like break tag for new line.

```
  <a href="#" title="hello <br> how are you" target="xxx"></a>
```

If its valid then break tag shows in tool tip which i want to avoid but still need a new line.

I am using jQuery.

I referred a link http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/N8Q2z/ in which i gave break tags in title. It just works fine in achieving new line without break tag being displayed in tool tip.

But not sure which part of the code is avoiding break tags in tool tip.

Can you please let me know which piece of code in jquery actually avoids break tags being displayed in tool tips as i am new to jquery.

Would appreciate all your help!!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Nop, that's not valid HTML.

Comment: According to the w3c validator there is no problem with it unless you're using xhtml,

Answer (score 4):

Try using `<br />` but use the values `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`. This will means that when the `title` is put into your tooltip it will be the correct format, and its valid!

Tested in IE7+, Chrome, Firefox.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zfFuu/)

```
<a title="hello&lt;br/&gt;how are you" class="printbtn" href="#">Print results</a><br>
```

Comment: This is the correct one as when the markup is parsed, the title attribute will contain `<br>` as text value, which in turn is thrown as html inside the tooltip by the plugin.

Comment: And you don't need that self-closing `/` in HTML. `=]` (those things belong to XML/XHTML but most html parsers will interpret it as syntactic sugar anyway)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté You're right, but both are valid and I'd rather write HTML that is also XML than not :)

Answer (score 2):

Use  `&#13;` or `&#xD;`

```
<a href="#" title="hello &#13; how are you" target="xxx"></a>
```

Comment: Guys upvoting.. You realize this answer doesn't work right. http://jsfiddle.net/N8Q2z/47/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I got a gut feeling, that jQuery is stripping out the `&#13;` it is not present in the tooltip text

Comment: It's a carriage return though, carriage returns in markup don't result in new lines on the rendered web page.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute values cannot contain tags. You can put new lines in the attribute values, but that's probably not a good idea.

It's a good time to think about why you want to put tags in the attribute and what you want to accomplish. I'm sure there are better ways.

Answer (score 1):

Title attribute should be a `text`.[Title Attribute Ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-title)

> title = text [CS];
>   This attribute offers advisory information about the element for which it is set.
>   Values of the title attribute may be rendered by user agents in a variety of ways. For instance, visual browsers frequently display the title as a "tool tip" (a short message that appears when the pointing device pauses over an object). Audio user agents may speak the title information in a similar context. For example, setting the attribute on a link allows user agents (visual and non-visual) to tell users about the nature of the linked resource:

Comment: If you give html tags as is it is not text it is an element... Probably worth running it through a validator...